# Array of structs example

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

i am bit new to structs in c#..

My question says:

> Write a console application that receives the following information for a set of students:
>   studentid, studentname, coursename, date-of-birth..
>   The application should also be able to display the information being entered..
>   Implement this using structs..

I have come up till this-->

```
struct student
{
    public int s_id;
    public String s_name, c_name, dob;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");
        s_id = Console.ReadLine();
        s_name = Console.ReadLine();
        c_name = Console.ReadLine();
        s_dob = Console.ReadLine();
        student[] arr = new student[4];
    }
}
```

Please help me after this..

Comment: You did not describe what you want to do.  If you don't know what you want to do then you cannot write code for it.  Nor can we.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've started right - now you just need to fill the each `student` structure in the array:

```
struct student
{
    public int s_id;
    public String s_name, c_name, dob;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student[] arr = new student[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");


            arr[i].s_id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            arr[i].s_name = Console.ReadLine();
            arr[i].c_name = Console.ReadLine();
            arr[i].s_dob = Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Now, just iterate once again and write these information to the console. I will let you do that, and I will let you try to make program to take any number of students, and not just 4.

Answer (score 1):

Given an instance of the struct, you set the values.

```
    student thisStudent;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");
    thisStudent.s_id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    thisStudent.s_name = Console.ReadLine();
    thisStudent.c_name = Console.ReadLine();
    thisStudent.s_dob = Console.ReadLine();
```

Note this code is incredibly fragile, since we aren't checking the input from the user at all.  And you aren't clear to the user that you expect each data point to be entered on a separate line.